# Slowness in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have cygwin and wsl installed on Windows 10.

Commands in cygwin run much slower than in wsl :

```
~$ uname; time date
CYGWIN_NT-10.0
Sat Nov 21 12:12:37 2020

real    0m0.825s
user    0m0.203s
sys     0m0.156s
```

```
~$ uname; time date
Linux
Sat Nov 21 12:12:36 2020

real    0m0.045s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.031s
```

Some online articles suggested removing /etc/{group,password}, I tried it, with no improvement.

What else can I try ?

Comment: you've discovered one of the selling points of WSL. comes down to differences in emulation strategy

Comment: The difficulty with Cygwin is that it is not *nix at all.  It’s windows .exe files pretending to be a *nix environment.  WSL is of course still windows but has been built into the Windows kernel (AFAIK).  This lets the Microsoft WSL authors make optimisations that Cygwin authors never could.

Comment: Still, there's no good justification for the `date` command to take almost a whole second! On my machine: `CYGWIN_NT-6.1` `real 0m0.018s`. Something's seriously wrong there.

Comment: Agreed. `real 0m0.019s` here. Even my older, slogging PC does sub-tenths: `0.095s`.

Comment: Strange. `real 0m0.056s` here with Cygwin 10.0 too

Answer (score 1):

Usually for such slow effect , it is the loading time and AV scanning

running 2 times in a row:

```
$ time date
Mon, Nov 30, 2020  5:39:14 PM

real    0m0.294s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.046s

$ time date
Mon, Nov 30, 2020  5:39:17 PM

real    0m0.046s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: Indeed, it seems to have something to do with AV, but not with AV scanning, as I ran the command at different times.